# Hosting Firebase realtime database in house

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firepad

I have a web application written in Angular 5.0,NodeJS as server and PostgreSQL as backend. I have integrated Firepad (https://firepad.io/) editor in my application to provide realtime editor functionality. Firepad editor uses Firebase realtime database. My client requirement is to host all application in house due to data privacy.

I would like to know how I can host Firebase realtime database in house, I looked at online and based on my research, I don't find any documentation or way to host Firebase realtime database in house.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase products are entirely cloud-hosted services that scale automatically.  There are currently no viable options for hosting its products on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In that case what are my options. Do we have any other real-time db available same as firebase realtime database ?